# How can I return data in this specific way

Tags: c#, json, repository-pattern, dapper

I am building an angularjs app with a c# backend with dapper micro orm which gets me data from the database.

I wanted the data returned to look like this:

```
[{
        "CategoryId": 1,
        "CategoryName": "cat1",
        "Items": [{
            "ItemId": 1,
            "ItemName": "Item1"
        }, {
            "ItemId": 2,
            "ItemName": "Item2"
        }]
    }, {
        "CategoryId": 2,
        "CategoryName": "cat2",
        "Items": [{
            "ItemId": 3,
            "ItemName": "Item3"
        }, {
            "ItemId": 4,
            "ItemName": "Item4"
        }]
    }
]
```

but this is what my data looks like

```
[{
        "CategoryId": 1,
        "CategoryName": "cat1",
        "Items": {
            "ItemId": 1,
            "ItemName": "Item1"
        }
    }, {
        "CategoryId": 1,
        "CategoryName": "cat1",
        "Items": {
            "ItemId": 2,
            "ItemName": "Item2"
        }
    },


    {
        "CategoryId": 2,
        "CategoryName": "cat2",
        "Items": {
            "ItemId": 3,
            "ItemName": "Item3"
        }
    },

    {
        "CategoryId": 2,
        "CategoryName": "cat2",
        "Items": {
            "ItemId": 4,
            "ItemName": "Item4"
        }
    }

]
```

This is what I have in my repository:

```
public IEnumerable<CategoryModel> GetAllCategories()
        {
            using (var conn = ConnectionSettings.GetSqlConnection())
                  {
                      const string sql = @" SELECT
                            c.CategoryName,     
                            c.CategoryId,
                            i.ItemId,
                            i.ItemName,                                
                            i.CategoryId 
                        from Category c
                        INNER JOIN item i ON  c.CategoryId = i.CategoryId";   


    var categoriesList = conn.Query<CategoryModel, ItemModel, CategoryModel>(sql, (cat, it) =>
                              {
                                  cat.Item = it;
                                  return cat;
                              }, splitOn: "ItemId");

                              return categoriesList;


                          }
        }
```

And these are my Category and Item Models

```
 public class CategoryModel
    {

        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }

        public ItemModel Item { get; set; }

    }


public class ItemModel
    {
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }

    }
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your `Item` property in `CategoryModel` should be a `List`. At the moment its an object and hence being deserialized like one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a following approach to achieve the expected result:

Modify the entities as shown below, use Newtonsoft Json attributes to ignore the `CategoryId` in the `ItemModel`, to avoid the serialization

```
[JsonObject]
public class CategoryModel
    {

        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        public string CategoryName { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<ItemModel> Items { get; set; }

    }

[JsonObject]
public class ItemModel
    {
        public int ItemId { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore] 
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        public string ItemName { get; set; }

    }
```

Now for fetching data, since its one to many mapping inside the `Category Model`, which contains multiple `Item Model`, use the `QueryMultiple` to fetch both the result sets separately, code will look like:

```
public IEnumerable<CategoryModel> GetAllCategories()
        {
            using (var conn = ConnectionSettings.GetSqlConnection())
                  {
                      const string sql = @" SELECT
                            c.CategoryName,     
                            c.CategoryId from Category c;
                            SELECT
                            i.ItemId,
                            i.ItemName,                                
                            i.CategoryId 
                        from item i";   


    var reader = conn.QueryMultiple(sql);

    IEnumerable<CategoryModel> categoriesList = reader.Read<CategoryModel>();

     IEnumerable<ItemModel> itemList = reader.Read<ItemModel>();


    foreach(Category c in categoriesList)
    {
       c.items = itemList.Where(i => i.CategoryId = c.CategoryId)
    }

    return categoriesList;


                          }
        }
```

Comment: There's a way to do it automatically, by extending GridReader class, but using Linq as I have shown would be preferable mechanism

Comment: Thanks I will give this a try. :)